# html image not displaying

Tags: html, image

I have to get the images from the database (oracle 10g) and display them, but I am unable to display the images. My code is:

```
<%  
    String[] salespersons;
    String[] name;
    String[] photoid;

    String tempid="", tempname="", tempphoto="";
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from Employees where ManagerID=" + managerid);
    while(rs.next()) {
        tempid += rs.getInt("id") + ";";
        tempname += rs.getString("firstname") + ";";
        tempphoto += rs.getString("photoid") + ";";
    }

    salespersons = tempid.split(";");
    name = tempname.split(";");
    photoid = tempphoto.split(";");
%>

<input type="button" value="CLOSE" onclick="window.close()" />
<table border="5" cellpadding="2" align="center">
<%
    for(int ite=0; ite < name.length; ite++) {
%>
        <tr>
        <td><a href="" onclick=""><%=salespersons[ite]%></a></td>
        <td><%=name[ite]%></td>            
        <td><img src="<%=photoid[ite]%>" alt="image not available"/></td>
        <td><a href="<%=photoid[ite]%>"></a></td>
<%
    }
%>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are the other elements displaying correctly (the 2 links and the value contained in `<%=name[ite]%>`)?

Comment: ya....no problem with the other two elements

Comment: Could you post the HTML output? Just the table should do.

Answer (score 0):

Image has a wrong path than only image not showing first print image path and then put it as a image url...

Comment: i did the same..and even included alt option in img tag,,but is is not showing alternative text also